# jsPlumb - How to get connection parameter

Tags: parameters, jsplumb, connection

I have two elements and the connection between them. When connection is established I set the parameter for this connection:

```js
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(e) {

 ........

 jsPlumb.select(e).setParameter('isNo','1');

 ........

});
```

It works ok.

How can I get parameter 'isNo' programmatically by click on button?

```js
<script>
$( "#getparam" ).on("click", function() {
 // How to get the connection parameter?
});
</script>
```

```html
<button id="getparam">Get connection param.</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I fixed the problem in this way:

```js
var getConn = jsPlumb.getConnections();

if(getConn.length > 0){
 $.each(getConn, function (e,s) {
  var parameters = s.getParameters();
  console.log(parameters.isNo);
 });
}
```